# Cannot index string with string while using recursion

Tags: json, jq

I'm attempting to parse this sample json using jq

```
{
  "config": {
    "env-1": {
      "LoadBalancerGroup": {
        "Algorithm": "weighted-round-robin",
        "LBGroupMembers": [
          {
            "Server": "10.183.191.131"
          },
          {
            "Server": "10.183.191.153"
          }
        ],
        "name": "LBG-https",
        "state": {
          "opstate": "up"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

env-1 key will vary, and I need to access using recursion (..) or similar technique

I'm stuck on the following error which is likely related to searching non hash nodes

```
cat recursion.json | jq  ' ..|.["LoadBalancerGroup"]|."name"?' | jq .
jq: error (at <stdin>:20): Cannot index string with string "LoadBalancerGroup"
null
null
"LBG-https"
null
```

trying select(type == "object" and has("name"))) and other suggestions have not solved this issue, and I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is clear enough. You can't index strings with strings, you need to select objects.

Assuming `LoadBalancerGroup` is always an object, and a null `name` being ignored is not a concern:

```
.. | objects | .LoadBalancerGroup.name // empty
```